# Conversion de fechas

Tags: php

Desde un campo `datetime` de un formulario, quiero convertir el formato de fecha extraido de ese campo. Pero me dá otra fecha distinta. Os dejo por aqui el código:

Campo `datetime`:

```
<input style="text-align: center;" type="datetime" name="fechahora" step="1" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s");?>">
```

Conversion:

```
$fyh = $_POST['fechahora'];
$fechaBD = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($fyh));
```

Para ese campo tengo un formato para que el usuario introduzca una fecha, por defecto tengo la actual. Una vez el usuario introduce la fecha que será en formato `d/m/Y H:i:s`, esta fecha es la que quiero cambiar a formato `Y-m-d H:i:s` para poder guardarla en la base de datos, pero al guardame la fecha en la base de datos, en vez de guardarme la fecha introducida por el usuario, lo que me guarda es esto `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: No se entiende del todo tu pregunta, pudieras editar y ser mas claro en lo que intentas y lo que estas obteniendo

Comment: @Aprendiz Ya está editado, espero que se pueda entender ahora

Comment: Has mirado que te devuelve en `$fyh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.- De acuerdo a la documentación de PHP en el apartado [date](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) indica que el formato para mostrar: año, mes y dia así como horas, minutos y segundos es el siguiente

```
$hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   // 2019-05-13 17:16:18 (el formato DATETIME de MySQL)
```

2.- Entonces tu primer cambio debe quedar a nivel del input así

```
<input style="text-align: center;" type="datetime" name="fechahora" step="1" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s");?>">
        <input type="submit" name="">
```

3.- En la vista se vería algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- Posterior en tu backend, donde recibes por `$_POST`dicho valor a la variable que almacena lo que el usuario manda

```
$fechahora = $_POST["fechahora"];
```

5.- Pásala por la instancia de la clase `DateTime()` de este modo

```
$resultado =  new DateTime($fechahora);
```

6.- Finalmente usa el método `format` para indicarle que ese valor que llega del frontend, va a cambiar su estructura por otra que tu defines

```
echo $resultado->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

7.- Del `echo` anterior obtendríamos como resultado lo siguiente

> 2019-05-13 09:06:50

Donde como notas el valor a mutado de ser `dd-mm-YYYY H:i:s` a ser ahora `YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s`

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Formatos de fechas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)
- [Clase DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Me devuelve el sigueinte error: `Caught exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (13/05/2019 08:00:00) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character `

Comment: cambia las diagonales por guiones medios en tu input @Maginon he probado este ejemplo y funciona

Comment: Perfecto! Por fin me ha servido! Muchas gracias!!